# When running the stored procedure "sp_table_privileges" in SQL Server 2014 why is the "IS_GRANTABLE" column a VARCHAR(3)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

Would it not make sense for a flag field in this case to be a bit value?

I went ahead and looked into the stored procedure and I see that it's generating from a view, could that have something to do with it?

[Screenshot from sys.sp_table_privileges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5rbT.png)

Comment: A view is not going to change the datatype unless it is done explicitly. It seems it is stored as a bit somewhere. Look at the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-table-privileges-transact-sql As to why it is a char(3)...well you would have to ask MS about that. We can't possibly know the reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you would have to ask MS as they made this decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-table-privileges-transact-sql, the IS_GRANTABLE column can be be YES, NO, or NULL. For these values, the VARCHAR(3) type seems an obvious choice.

If your question was why Microsoft chose to return YES, NO, or NULL (instead 1, 0, or NULL), I would guess it's one (or both) of these:

- the return values are similar to the SQLTablePriviledges ODBC function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqltableprivileges-function) and this function is present since the ODBC 1.0 specification, adopted in 1992
- a text value is more clear (for a human) than a bit value